# .Net core dependency injection, Is this a new instance of SmtpClient for each request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, smtpclient

We are injecting a custom mailer that accepts `SmtpClient` as a parameter, based on whether we are debugging or not we use a slightly different implementation of `SmtpClient`:

```
public static void AddSmtpMailer(this IServiceCollection services, IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
    services.AddTransient<IMailer<BaseModel>>(x => new Mailer<BaseModel>(
        environment.IsDevelopment()
            ? new SmtpClient
            {
                PickupDirectoryLocation = @"c:\temp",
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory
            }
        : new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "mail.someplace.com",
            Port = 25,
            EnableSsl = true,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password")
        },
        environment.ContentRootPath, environment.IsLive()));
}
```

However we are finding that when we attempt to send multiple emails in quick succession, we get this error:
[image: error message]

My question therefore is: Are we getting a new instance of `SmtpClient` each time? Because it appears to be an issue related to sending multiple emails with the same `SmtpClient`. Are we creating a single instance of `SmtpClient` at startup and reusing it each time?

Note, we have also tried `.AddScoped` but found the same behavior.

the actual code that uses the SmtpClient is:

```
 public sealed class Mailer<T> :IDisposable, IMailer<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    private readonly SmtpClient _smtpClient;
    private readonly string _contentRootPath;
    private readonly bool _forceSandbox;

    public Mailer(SmtpClient smtpClient, string contentRootPath, bool isLive)
    {
        _smtpClient = smtpClient;
        _contentRootPath = contentRootPath;
        _forceSandbox = !isLive;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SendEmail(T model, string template)
    {
        if (template.Contains(".cshtml"))
            template = template.Replace(".cshtml", "");

        Email.DefaultSender = new SmtpSender(_smtpClient);
        Email.DefaultRenderer = new RazorRenderer();

        var email = Email
            .From(model.From.Email, model.From.Name.NullOrEmptyTo(model.From.Email))
            .To(EmailAddressHelper.GetAddressesFromModel(model.Recipients, _forceSandbox))
            .Subject(model.Subject)
            .UsingTemplateFromFile($@"{_contentRootPath}\views\{template}.cshtml", model)
            .Attach(EmailAttachmentHelper.GetAttachmentsFromModel(model.Attachments));

        if (model.CcRecipients != null && model.CcRecipients.Any())
            email.CC(EmailAddressHelper.GetAddressesFromModel(model.CcRecipients, _forceSandbox));

        if (model.BccRecipients != null && model.BccRecipients.Any())
            email.BCC(EmailAddressHelper.GetAddressesFromModel(model.BccRecipients, _forceSandbox));

        email.Data.Headers = EmailHeaderHelper.GetHeaders(model.UniqueID, model.Headers);

        var result = await email.SendAsync();
        return result.Successful;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _smtpClient?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort answer: YES

Comment: Do you need a single instance?

Comment: @Nkosi No, I want a new instance each time.

Comment: Ok what you have shown so far will create a new instance of SmtpClient when the mailer is resolved.

Comment: Are you aware of this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: How are you making the call? from the stack trace is looks like you are not calling the correct async member. await `SendMailAsync`

Comment: The mailer is injected into the controller, then it is just  var result = await _mailer.SendEmail(model, template); Added some code to the question to demonstrate.

Comment: What member does the mailer call on the client

Comment: Not seeing the SmtpClient in the additional code.

Comment: It's a property of the class _smtpClient. We are using FluentMailer for the emailing, which uses SmtpClient. I have extended the sample to make it clearer.

Comment: As @Nkosi noticed, have you tried with `SendMailAsync` ?

Comment: It looks like it uses SendMailExAsync() under the covers

Comment: Do we have to new up the SmtpClient or is there any way to inject it via DI?